# Flash game - configure stage dimensions for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, dimensions, stage

I'm developing an actionscript game made for web. However, I want to port it for android devices as well. The orientation of the game is static (landscape). How can I configure the stage size in order to have a full screen game in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

More info in Adobe's documentation :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html

Answer (score 0):

The exact screen size (in fullscreen, without battery or signal icon bar) is defined with

```
var SW:int = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
var SH:int = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

Either you can zoom your application with a ratio based on your flash stage size, or you can set all your elements with your phone's screen size.
For example if your flash is 320x480, your Zoom variable is :

```
if(SW > 320 && SH > 480){
    if (SW / 320 < SH / 480) {
        ZOOM = SW / 320;
    }else {
        ZOOM = SH / 480;
    }
}
```

Then you have ZOOM = 1.5 if your phone is 480x800 (most of android).

Answer (score 0):

In my game, I used:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

In app's xml file I hadsomething like this:

```
<initialWindow> 
     ... 
    <fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
</initialWindow>
```

and for detection of width/height i used:

```
stage.fullScreenWidth
stage.fullScreenHeight
```

and then I positioned all elements accordingly. You cannot just "set" stage size. Maybe you want to read this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html